# How do i check if a machine is up and running using an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

i'm trying to write an ansible playbook to check if a set of machines are up and running.

Let's say, I've 5 machines to test. I'm trying to understand if I can have a playbook to capture status(up or down) of all 5 machines by checking one by one sequentially without failing the play if one of the machine is down.

Comment: This is more of a use case for monitoring than Ansible.

Comment: i know it sounds more like a monitoring stuff but the actual requirement behind this is more than just checking the machines' status. Let me give you little more details. I'm trying to write an ansible playbook to sleep and wake a specific infra like a DB because we don't want these huge machines up and running all the time and this sleep script would help the Ops team to simply run one command to suspend/pause the machine instead of shutting it down completely. With that said, I want to check each machines' availability before issuing a command to stop or start the service. Hope that helps

Comment: What's wrong with ansible ping?

Comment: @zhqiat as per the Ansible documentation, ping is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node on. I'm not very confident that I can get python on those remote machines, so can't use ping .https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html#wait-for-connection-waits-until-remote-system-is-reachable-usable) in the [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html). For example

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - wait_for_connection:
            sleep: 1
            timeout: 10
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} not connected. End of host."
        - meta: clear_host_errors
        - meta: end_host

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} is running"
    - setup:
```